# How to show text in image using pillow

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I recently started to learn how to work with Pillow in python and this is what i have so far (code below).

If i run this i get the following error:

> ValueError: cannot determine region size; use 4-item box

i've tried removing the base.paste line, this removes the error but doesn't show any text.

i hope someone here could help me to fix this so the text is showing in the image.

````py
@app.route("/imgtest/")
def imgtest():
    f_text = textwrap.fill(request.args.get('text'), 10)
    base = Image.open(config.assetsfolder+'/'+'facts.bmp').convert("RGBA")
    txtO = Image.new("RGBA", base.size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
    font = ImageFont.truetype(config.assetsfolder+'/'+'fonts'+'/'+'Roboto-Bold.ttf', 15)

    canv = ImageDraw.Draw(txtO)
    canv.text((95, 283), f_text, font=font, fill="Black")
    base.paste(f_text)
    base.save(config.assetsfolder+'/'+'done'+'/'+'boop.png')
    return send_file(config.assetsfolder+'/'+'done'+'/'+'boop.png')```

How do i show the text in the image?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played a bit around by adding some random code and reading the docs a bit better

```py
@app.route("/fact/")
def fact():
    filename=(config.assetsfolder+'/'+'facts.bmp')
    args=request.args.get('text')
    font = ImageFont.truetype(config.assetsfolder+'/'+'fonts'+'/'+'Roboto-Bold.ttf', size=20)
    text = wrap(font, args, 340)

    im = Image.open(filename)
    text_layer = Image.new('RGBA', im.size)

    d = ImageDraw.Draw(text_layer)

    location = (90, 600)
    text_color = (20, 20, 20)
    d.text(location, text, font=font, fill=text_color)
    text_layer = text_layer.rotate(-13, resample=Image.BICUBIC)
    im.paste(text_layer, (0, 0), text_layer)
    im.save(config.assetsfolder+'/'+'done'+'/'+'fact.png')
    return send_file(config.assetsfolder+'/'+'done'+'/'+'fact.png')
```

This did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pillow 4.0, I believe this would be an issue with the pillow version. Try in your cmd the following:

```
 pip uninstall pillow
 pip install Pillow==3.4.2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

I tried this and got this big error 
[link to hastebin](https://haste.xaetacore.pro/cigovanile.sql)

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: i'm using Debian 9 with python3.7